# Swift ARKit SceneView nil when adding 3D object from different viewcontroller

Tags: ios, swift, augmented-reality

In my storyboard, I have 2 simple viewController. The view which shows up at start of the app with simple layout which contains a button. When clicking on a button, segue by showing the second viewController which houses ARSCNView.

```
    @IBOutlet weak var sceneView: ARSCNView!
```

In viewDidLoad, I am able to add 3D object, also have a touchBegin to show additional 3D object when tapped on the plane. Works great.

However my first viewController needs to trigger adding 3D object onto the scene upon certain delegate that happens in my first viewController. First viewController simply calls a function on my 2nd viewController to add 3D object (same function that I use to add 3D object when tapped on the plane).

```
    secondViewController.add3DObject()
```

When it calls add3DObject from my first viewController, sceneView is nil.

When I'm able to add 3D object which gets triggered by second viewController, why am I not able to trigger the same thing by different viewController?

First viewController: (omitting whole bunch of code not relevant to issue)

```
    class ViewController: UIViewController, CLLocationManagerDelegate {

       var locationManager = CLLocationManager()
       var arSceneViewController = ARSceneViewController() //second viewController

        func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateHeading newHeading: CLHeading) {
         // omitting some logic here....
         // call a function in second view controller
         arSceneViewController.addARItems(item: item)
        }
    }
```

second viewController: (omitting whole bunch of code not relevant to issue)

```
    class ARSceneViewController: UIViewController, ARSCNViewDelegate {

        @IBOutlet weak var sceneView: ARSCNView!

         // this works 
         override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
             if let touch = touches.first{
             let touchLocation = touch.location(in: sceneView)

             let results = sceneView.hitTest(touchLocation, types: .existingPlaneUsingExtent)
             var arItem = ARItem()
             arItem.itemDescription = "hello"
            if let hitResult = results.first{
                // calling this works from here
                addARItems(item: arItem ,atLocation: hitResult)
            }
        }
      }

    // Called from first ViewController doesn't work
    // Called from the same file work (from touchesBegin)
    func addARItems(item: ARItem, atLocation location:ARHitTestResult? = nil){
        // sceneView is nil!!!
        guard let sView =  sceneView else { return }       

        // omitted some insignificant code here ...

        let cube = SCNBox(width:0.5, height: 0.1, length: 0.1, chamferRadius: 0.01)
        let node = SCNNode()
        node.position = SCNVector3(0, 0.1, -0.5)
        node.geometry = cube

        sceneView.scene.rootNode.addChildNode(node)
    }

}
```

Comment: Could you post some more detailed code here so that it will be easier for us to help you identify the problem?

Comment: Added some code sample above. Hope this make sense.

Comment: In the first view controller `var arSceneViewController = ARSceneViewController() //second viewController` I think here you should init the second view controller from storyboard?

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion...I'm new to Swift. Can you elaborate on how I would go about doing that please?

Comment: Ok I will post the code as my answer, you can try and let me know if it works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As discussed, I hope this code works for you.

When clicking on a button, segue by showing the second viewController which houses ARSCNView. --> So we will get the second view controller by overriding the func prepare for segue (please replace "your segue id for second view controller" with the actual identifier you set in the storyboard) .

And in the delegate locationManager didUpdateHeading, we will check if the second view controller is there and then we call addARItems

```
var arSceneViewController: ARSceneViewController? //second viewController

override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == "your segue id for second view controller" {
        arSceneViewController = segue.destination as? ARSceneViewController
    }
}

func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateHeading newHeading: CLHeading) {
    // omitting some logic here....
    // call a function in second view controller
    if let arSceneVC = arSceneViewController {
         arSceneVC.addARItems(item: item)
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help!! This worked. Is it a requirement to always have prepare for segue? I only had it in the storyboard.

Comment: Glad that it helps you. Actually it depends on how you set up your storyboard. If you  config a segue to push to a new view controller, then you have to override that method to get the destination view controller. Otherwise, if you trigger manual push/present, then you initiate the second view controller from storyboard and keep a reference to it for using.